# How to describe Support Vector Machine formula onto the Quadratic Programming objective function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, quadratic-programming

[image]

Assume that we have two lines. Green and blue line.

$$w^Tx - b = 1$$
$$w^Tx - b = -1$$

Our goal is to find $w$ and $b$ here.

The first we can do, is to find the distance between these two lines.

We first find the ratio between $x^+$ and $x^−$. They are coordinates of $x$ that can describe

$$w^Tx^+ - b = 1$$
$$w^Tx^− - b = -1$$

So $x \in x^+, x^−$

The ratio between $x^+$ and $x^−$ is

$$x^+ = x^− + \lambda w$$

Where $\lambda$ is the distance between the two lines. If we using

$$w^Tx^+ - b = 1$$

and add in

$$x^+ = x^− + \lambda w$$

We will get this:

$$w^T(x^− + \lambda w) - b = 1$$
$$w^Tx^− + \lambda w^Tw - b = 1$$

And notice that $w^Tx^− -b$ is $-1$

$$-1 +\lambda w^Tw = 1$$

And now it will become

$$\lambda w^Tw = 2$$

We want to have the distance by it self

$$\lambda = \frac{2}{w^Tw}$$

And we need to make sure that $\lambda$ is always a positive number, so we are taking $$||\lambda|| = \frac{||2||}{||w||} = \frac{2}{||w||}$$

**Question:**

The number $||\lambda||$ need to be equal to 2, then the lines is optimized. Because the perdendicular distance between these two lines are 2.

The quadratic programming problem is:

$$\frac{1}{2}w^TQw + c^Tw$$

Where the constraints are:

$$Aw \leq d$$
$$w \geq 0$$

How can I describe the support vector machine formula, onto the quadratic programming objective function?

Comment: Why are you taking the norm of a scalar?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes. You can see the lecture notes here: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dyer/cs540/notes/10_svm.pdf